# select only several files from an ftp through getURL

Tags: r, list, date, rcurl

Could anyone help me with an RCurl issue in [R]?

I'd like to download from an ftp data saved in a directory as files with this name pattern:
DMT143_YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MIN_SS.txt

I don't want to download all the files in the directory, but only those in between given dates. I was wondering if it is easy to program that using RCurl. For the moment I can download all the list of files but it would work unnecessarily if I'm only interested in a certain period, so I have to improve it.

I'm using:

```
filenames <- getURL(url, dirlistonly = TRUE)
filenames <- paste(url, strsplit(filenames, "\r*\n")[[1]], sep = "")
```

I would really appreciate if you could give me some insight.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you paste a sample of what your `filenames` variable looks like after running your code ?